# Creating graphical programs using VC++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, graphics, exe

I would like to make a graphical application using Visual Studio 2010.  I am trying to use C++ and have the app run natively on windows 7 straight out of an exe.  Please give me some suggestions for what libraries to include as well as general concepts or a help document for it.

I know the question is broad, but I am only looking for broad answers.

Thanks

Comment: it really depends on which version of Windows you are targeting if you want to build a native GUI, otherwise you go for something like Qt that is a cross-platform and fairly portable solution. http://qt-project.org/

Comment: The problem with such an overly-broad question is people can write good answers that are no use to you, combined with the fact it *suggests* the poster has done little to no research of their own, it's unlikely to get quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

The "basement of everything" is the [windows "hello world"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)
and all the windows API and related usage.

You can easily start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you are interested in other platforms, the equivalent base forn *nix (and linux-) derived systems are the [X11 API](http://www.x.org/docs/X11/xlib.pdf).

There are then framework libraries that wrap both Windows or X API exposing a same consistent interface, like

- [WxWidget](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
- [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/)
- [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)
- [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/index.php)
- [Nana](http://nanapro.sourceforge.net/)

Some are easier, some more complete, some other even overkill.
But it's mostly all about taste.

Comment: Although X11 is the de facto base graphics API on Unix, it is not friendly, useful, nor future proof. I would strongly suggest using Qt or GTK, which will work on e.g. Future Wayland based systems. Now that I think about this, the Win32 API isn't friendly either, although it'll work until the end of days :-)

Comment: The general problem is that none of those (apart nana, maybe) is conceived around a "modern" use of C++: they've all been conceived on top of C99 wrapping it with C with classes (pre-ANSI C++), with almost no "boost-ification", to give an over inflated OOP design (the infamous "god-object" antipattern).  By a language stand point they are "unfriendly" exactly as what they wrap.

Answer (score 1):

VC++ provides Windows Forms for GUI development and GDI+ for 2D graphics, built-in and full-fledged. What more do you need ?